# Why private variable only increase one time even its called more than one

Tags: java, class, static-members

I am new to java and trying to understand why `a` doesnt get increase even if `a++` runs 3 times but only one time increased.

why another 2 instance doesnt make same behaviour as first instance, which principle doing this?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tpcg.php?p=Y0VNTH

```
  public class ClassicSingleton {
   private int a = 0;
   static int b = 0;
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;

   private ClassicSingleton() {

     a++; 
     System.out.println(a); 
     System.out.println("ClassicSingleton() called"); 

   }

   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      b++;
      System.out.println("b:"+b); 
      instance = new ClassicSingleton();

      return instance;
   }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ClassicSingleton tmp = ClassicSingleton.getInstance( );
      ClassicSingleton tmp2 = ClassicSingleton.getInstance( );
      ClassicSingleton tmp3 = ClassicSingleton.getInstance( );

   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a` is an instance variable, which means each of the three `ClassicSingleton` class you create in your main method has its own copy of that variable, which is initialized to 0 (by default) and incremented to 1 by the constructor.

BTW, `ClassicSingleton` is a misleading name here, since your `ClassicSingleton.getInstance()` returns a new instance on each call. Even if it was returning the same instance in each call, `a` would still contain 1 (since this time you would have a single `ClassicSingleton` instance, for which `a` will be incremented just once).

Oh, and if you want `ClassicSingleton` to be an actual singleton, change `getInstance` to:

```
public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ClassicSingleton();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Basically `a in tmp, tmp2 and tmp3` are completly independent, across all instances of this class. So your singleton is not a singleton at all, check eg. this tutorial for clarify https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html scope for checking if instance is null or not

Comment: @Kad The `instance` variable should only keep a reference to a single instance. That's the point of the singleton pattern - just one instance of the class is created.

Comment: @Eran  If variable gets first value on every instance creation how we make singleton like this?  `private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;`   link: http://tpcg.io/C4Gim5

Comment: @Kad well, you have the `b` variable, which tracks how many times `getInstance` was called. Incrementing a variable (such as `a`) in the constructor would be meaningless in a singleton class, since it would only be incremented once.

Comment: @Eran i dont want to make singleton classname just remained from example

Comment: @Kad In that case, you can cancel the `instance` variable. You can change `a` to be `static` if you want to maintain a counter of the number of instances that were created.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons

1. `a` is an instance variable that is incremented only *once* - on construction
2. you create a new instance every time you call `getInstance`, which replaces the shared instance with a new one. Basically, you've implemented the classic singleton wrong and implemented a factory method instead.

To fix the singleton, make a check  if `instance` is null and only create a new instance if that's the case.